# Optaplanner: Can I dynamically create constraints for a particular solver?

Tags: optaplanner, constraint-programming

I have a `ConstraintProvider` that looks something like this:

```kotlin
class MyConstraintProvider : ConstraintProvider {
    override fun defineConstraints(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory): Array<Constraint> {
        return arrayOf(
            neverUse(constraintFactory, 1),
        )
    }

    fun neverUse(constraintFactory: ConstraintFactory, cpId: Int): Constraint {
        return constraintFactory.forEach(MyEntity::class.java)
            .filter { myEntity: MyEntity -> myEntity.cpId == cpId }
            .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD)
            .asConstraint("neverUse-$cpId")
    }
}
```

The `neverUse` constraint is dynamic in that it takes the `cpId` parameter for the constraint.

Each time I solve this, I need to be able to use this constraint with a different value for the `cpId` parameter -- and possibly use multiple instances of this constraint (or others) with different parameters.

What I think I need is to be able to instantiate a new `ConstraintProvider` (which I could load up with constraints on the fly) for each solver that I create. Is this possible?

Comment: It's not possible to instantiate the `ConstraintProvider`; in the configuration, you specify the `ConstraintProvider` class and OptaPlanner creates the instance. Could you clarify what you are trying to achieve by these parameters?
This particular example effectively partitions the entity collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that `cpId` influences the penalize's score level or score weight, or disables the constraint entirely, look for `@ConstraintWeight` and `penalizeConfigurable()` in the docs.

Otherwise, add a `@ProblemFactProperty` on your input `@PlanningSolution` that returns an object that holds your `cpId` value. Then you can change it per dataset you want to solve, without worrying about race conditions.